# TURN server XOR-RELAYED-ADDRESS IP different from its own public IP

Tags: networking, nat-traversal, stun

Suppose I am running a TURN server bound to a public IP (say 100.0.0.1). When the server creates a relay port for a create allocation request, is it ever the case that the server would send back an IP address that is different from whatever it is bound to (100.0.0.1 in this case) in the XOR-RELAYED-ADDRESS attribute? I'm not familiar enough with networking to know all possible scenarios, and the [RFC 5766](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5766#section-6.2) doesn't really say anything specific (as far as I can tell).

Phrased another way, is the IP address in the XOR-RELAYED-ADDRESS redundant? In all cases I have considered, the client only needs to know the port allocated, and could completely ignore the IP of XOR-RELAYED-ADDRESS. As long as the client knows the relay port, it can always send relay data to the TURN server public IP (it already knows the IP since it had to connect initially...) at the relay port.

Any comments?

Answer (score 1):

If you server is not behind a NAT (on the public internet with a public IP address assigned to it), then the IP address returned in XOR-RELAYED-ADDRESS will be the same.  (It will always be the same as the IP address assigned to its NIC).

I assume the reason you are considering ignoring XOR-RELAYED-ADDRESS is related to you other question suggesting the TURN server will actually be behind a NAT/firewall.  I think you'll find that the IP address is predictable.  But the Firewall/NAT your server sits behind has the possibility of messing up the port allocations.  Make sure you understand how the TURN server does port assignments, and that your firewall does port forwarding correctly.

One bit of nomenclature clarification.  Your server isn't "bound" to a public or a private IP.  Your server socket binds to an interface that has an IP address assigned and associated to it.

Comment: In my situation, the NAT forwards ports directly. Thanks for the nomenclature note :)

Comment: Then you are good to go with having the client assume the IP address.

Comment: Does this mean that if my TURN server is behind a NAT/Firewall it will still work ? I am having similar issue the relay address is same as the local address while I have used port forwarding from my public IP to local ip on port 3478.

Comment: @BilboBaggins - you should be able to configure a TURN server to work behind a NAT. But you should probably forward the entire range of ports the server offers for relay and not just 3478.  Most TURN servers have some sort of command line parameter or config file setting for specifying a port range.

Comment: ohk, Please I am clarifying a bit, you mean to say I have to do the port forwarding for almost every port and not just 3478? Have I understood it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you guys both overlooked a situation when the relay IP address and different from listening IP address, on the TURN server. The TURN Server may be listening on, say, address 1.2.3.4, but it may be allocating the relayed endpoint on two other public addresses - like 2.3.4.5 and 3.4.5.6. The real relayed IP address is returned in `XOR-RELAYED-ADDRESS` and it may be very different from the listening address.